# php script restarts randomly with same POST data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php script that receives parsed data from a javascript application via xmlhttp.

I'm finding that the php script will sometimes stop while it's processing a chunk of data and restart with the same POST data that was sent to it. I thought that maybe the javascript's xmlhttp might be double firing somehow, but I've ruled that out with an inProgress flag as shown below.

```
function SendPHP(str, callback){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    str = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str);   
    xmlhttp.open("POST","sendmail.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            inProgress=false;
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        if (inProgress==false){
          inProgress=true;
        xmlhttp.send(str);
        }
        else{
            writeDisplayConsole("ERROR: xmlhttp fired twice!");
        }
}
```

If the xmlhttp tries to send twice then that error is shown and no further packets will be sent. But that's never the case so the php script must be restarting on it's own.

Bear in mind that it happens at random intervals, not at the same time every time with the same data. What could be causing this to happen?

The php script frequently writes to big text file logs, could that be something to do with it?

Here's the php (but since the error happens at random intervals with the same data, I'm not sure how it could be a problem with the php code):

```
<?php

writelog("\n*** Sendmail script started ***");

$q = $_POST['q'];


   //Split auth code and verify
     $pieces = explode("(<!asplit!>)", $q);
     $authc=$pieces[0];
     $q=$pieces[1];

     if ($authc<>"****"){
            echo "!Authentification denied.";
            writelog ("Authentification denied");
            die;
     }

         writelog ("Authentification accepted");




     //Split off packet details
     $pieces=explode("(<!psplit!>)", $q);
     $tpack=$pieces[0];
     $q=$pieces[1];

     $pieces=explode("-", $tpack);
     $tpacket=$pieces[0];
     $ofpacket=$pieces[1];
     $totalcontacts=$pieces[2]; 

     //Split contact data from email message
     $pieces = explode("(<!dsplit!>)", $q);
     $split=$pieces[0];
     $q=$pieces[1];

     //Assign contacts to array
     $contacts = explode ("<!", $split);
     $tcount=count($contacts);
     $tcount=$tcount-1;

     echo "(PACKET ";
     echo $tpacket;
     echo " OF ";
     echo $ofpacket;
     echo ")- ";

     writelog("(PACKET " . $tpacket . " of " . $ofpacket . ")");

         //Killswitch check incase double run
     checkKillSwitch("!Startup aborted as Power set to off.",0);
     checkKillSwitch("!Aborted, Killswitch set to Kill",1);
     file_put_contents('log/killswitch.txt', "on");

     echo $tcount;
     echo " contacts processing...";

     foreach ($contacts as &$value) {

     //check killswitch
     checkKillSwitch("Killswitch aborted during runtime",1);

                     $split=explode ("^!", $value);

            //Get the contact's details
         $firstname= $split[0];
         $lastname= $split[1];
                 $temail = $split[2];

                 if ($firstname<>""){

           $mainmessage=str_replace("[firstname]",$firstname,$q);
             $mainmessage=str_replace("[lastname]",$lastname,$mainmessage);


           //Split off subject
             $pieces = explode("(/subject)", $mainmessage);
             $tsubject=$pieces[0];
             $mainmessage=$pieces[1];

                    testLogMail($temail, $tsubject, $mainmessage);

                //log progress      
                $adder=$adder+1;

                    //For the log, show progress of total (based on 10 per packet change if different)
                    $tadder = (($tpacket-1)*10)+$adder;

                    echo ($tadder . ".");

                    writelog($tadder . " of " . $totalcontacts . " processed >> " . $temail);
                    sleep(rand(2,20));

                }   

     }

function testLogMail($xaddress, $xsubject, $xmessage){

  $tdate=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

  $file = 'log/testmaillog.txt';
  // Open the file to get existing content
  $current = file_get_contents($file);

    // Enter email
    $towrite="To: ".$xaddress."\n";
    $towrite.="Subject: ".$xsubject."\n";
    $towrite.="Date: ".$tdate."\n";
    $towrite.="...\n";
  $towrite.=$xmessage."\n";
    $towrite.="___________________________________\n\n";

    $current .= $towrite;

  // Write the contents back to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $current);

}

 function writelog($towrite)
{
  $tdate=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

  $file = 'log/testlog.txt';
  // Open the file to get existing content
  $current = file_get_contents($file);
  // Append a new person to the file
  $current .= $towrite." --- ".$tdate."\n";
  // Write the contents back to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $current);
} 

function checkKillSwitch($towrite, $killtype){

if ($killtype==0){
   $killswitch = file_get_contents('log/killswitch.txt');

   if ($killswitch=="on") {
    echo $towrite;
    writelog($towrite);
    die;
   }
 }

 if ($killtype==1){
   $killswitch = file_get_contents('log/killswitch.txt');

   if ($killswitch=="kill") {
    echo $towrite;
    writelog($towrite);
    die;
   }
 }


}


writelog("*** Sendmail script ended ***");
?>
```

Comment: Where did you define `inProgress`>?

Comment: It's global, I've tested it and it works.

Comment: What does your PHP code look like?

Comment: I'll edit it to show the php, one sec

Comment: I've added the php, it's quite long. But if the error happens at different times with the same data, I can't see how it's a problem with my code.

Comment: Have you double-checked your access log to confirm the browser isn't calling the script twice? Might be a browser extension doing this (e.g. AdBlock).

Comment: Can the browser do this with data from my javascript?